# How can I import Log in java?

Tags: java, logging, import, importerror

I tried using these 2 imports:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
```

But I get the error *Cannot resolve symbol commons*. Does anyone have any clue why ? Also, `java.util.logging` works for me, but I need LogFactory. I'm using jdk 1.8.0.

Comment: do you add the jar to your build path?

Comment: Looks like you are missing some libraries.  See http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1 for example (Maven).  Or manually add the jar files to the project.  But I would suggest using Maven or Gradle for example.

Comment: are u working with a maven project ?

Comment: @GunaTulips I'm using a gradle project.

Comment: @3kings I'm not sure how to do that, I googled and tried a few things but none of them worked so far.

Comment: Just add it as a gradle dependency.

Comment: 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1'
 add this dependency in your build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import a class in a source code file, you need two things.

1. The `import` statement, which you have.
2. The jar file containing that class, on your compile classpath.

I'll wager you're missing the latter, and this one can be downloaded from Apache.org.

Note that to run the program, you will also need that jar file on the runtime classpath.

---

The reason that `java.util.logging` works just fine is because it is part of the "core JVM libraries" which are automatically added to the compile and runtime classpaths for all Java programs.  These "core JVM libraries" also include the definitions for things like `java.util.List` and `java.lang.Object`.